# I'm lost on how to create a functioning search bar django/react

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework, react-redux, django-filter

On my ecommerce project I wanna impelement a search bar where you can search products by name through drf api, I installed django_filters and created a class like so:

```
class ProductFilter(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    filter_backends = [filters.SearchFilter]
    search_fields = ['^name']
```

I tested the endpoint and it works but I don't know how to make it work on the frontend part with react, I have the saerchbar in the header like so:

```
<Form className="d-flex">
 <Form.Control
   type="search"
   placeholder="Search"
   className="me-2"
   aria-label="Search"
 />
 <Button variant="outline-success">Search</Button>
</Form>
```

Using axios for api calls, I have no idea how to set this up and if I need reducers, actions, store too

Comment: what have you tried for the axios call? All you'll need is a call to your endpoint with the search field and value in the body of your call. You shouldn't need any of the special React features like reducers/actions/store for simply sending an API call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can create a function which will make an api call when user enters any text in the input. Also, debounce it to avoid frequent api calls.

```js
import React, { useCallback } from "react";

// Debounce to avoid frequent api calls
export const debounce = (func, waitFor) => {
  let timeout = null;

  const debounced = (...args) => {
    if (timeout !== null) {
      clearTimeout(timeout);
      timeout = null;
    }
    timeout = setTimeout(() => func(...args), waitFor);
  };

  return debounced;
};

const TestComponent = () => {
  // debounce the function so that we send api calls once user stops typing
  const searchSomething = useCallback(
    debounce(async (value) => {
      try {
        // Make your api call using whichever library you are using
        // let response = await fetch(`${YOUR_SERVER_URL}/search?query=${value}`);
        let response =  axios.get(`${YOUR_SERVER_URL}/search?query=${value}`)
        console.log(response);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }, 500),
    []
  );

  return (
    <Form className="d-flex">
      <Form.Control
        type="search"
        placeholder="Search"
        className="me-2"
        aria-label="Search"
        onChange={(e) => {
          searchSomething(e.target.value);
        }}
      />
      <Button variant="outline-success">Search</Button>
    </Form>
  );
};

export default TestComponent;
```

Comment: This seems unnecessarily complex - they already have a search button there's no need to implement auto submit and async calls. It seems like they're asking how to implement an API call using Axios, and here you've used fetch instead.

Comment: And that should be in the header componnet or I should create a seperate search component or screen? @shubham-waje

Comment: @Khaled I would say if that component is getting used in multiple places its better to create a reusable separate component which will help in code splitting. But if you think it is only specific to header then keep it in head only. Let me know if you have any other questions :)

Comment: @pzutils doesn't matter if he uses axios or fetch the important point here is how we can connect search to the backend and what would be the frontend flow. Either he uses axios or fetch it will work the same. Important point here is we should debounce the search function so we can limit the number of api calls to the server

Comment: It says "search" is not defined, the one given to value in FormControl @shubham-waje

Comment: just seems like a very complicated answer for someone who is simply asking how to form an axios call but hey if it helps great

Comment: Django also has built in throttling features to limit API calls https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/throttling/

Comment: and yes I realize it doesn't "matter" if they use fetch or axios, but why not answer the actual question that was asked

Comment: @Khaled I have updated the code please check once :)

Comment: @pzutils let's not argue over it and help others :) I have posted an answer which I have used in the production.

Comment: Search wasn't successful, I get this url "http://localhost:3000/?" when I used this: ```axios.get(`${"/api/search"}/?search=${value}`)``` and this ```axios.get(`${/api/search}/search?query=${value}```, this is my server value ```/api/search/?search=iphone``` that works in the backend @shubham-waje

Comment: I did check the edited comment and I didn't downvote your answer as well @shubham-waje

Comment: Okay no problem. Please let me know if you have further queries. And as per the scalability this is a good approach and I have used this in the production. You can do some research on debouncing and why we use this while searching anything. Cheers!

Comment: I seem to get the correct data in the console but not rendering on the page @shubham-waje

Comment: Create a state locally in the component and where you are console logging the data after api call set that inside that state and render that state inside the JSX.

Answer (score 0):

Your `axios` call should end up something like this:

```
axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: '/login', // replace with your endpoint URL
  data: {
    searchField.name: searchField.value,
  }
});
```

with searchField.name being whatever field name Django is expecting to receive on the back end (it looks like it's `name` here), and searchField.value being the value of the search field.

Comment: I didn't downvoted it @pzutils